# Custom method for console write line and assigning value to variable - C#

Tags: c#

I made a custom method to print line and then read user input to assign it to double variable 
here is my code :

```
 double result = 0;
 double a, b;
 while (true)
            {


                if (Double.TryParse(GetValue("Enter value for a "), out a)
                    && Double.TryParse(GetValue("Enter value for b "), out b))
                {
                    result = a + b;
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("invalid value please try again..");
                    continue;
                }
}
       public static double GetValue(string input )
        {
            double z1;
            double value;

                Console.WriteLine(input);
                value = Console.ReadLine();
                z1 = value;
                return z1;
          }
```

but am facing an error which is that I can't convert 'double' to 'string' 
. Can someone explain what am doing wrong ?

Comment: You need to parse console input. It's a string, you want a double. Double.TryParse

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is in the line

```
value = Console.ReadLine();
```

but you probably knew that already. ReadLine returns a string.

The easiest fix would be to return a string from GetValue, since you already try to parse it outside of the function:

```
public static string GetValue(string input )
{
    Console.WriteLine(input);
    return Console.ReadLine();
}
```

But an arguably cleaner solution would be to solve it in the function that asks the input and return a double from there:

```
double result;
double a, b;

a = GetValue("Enter value for a ");
b = GetValue("Enter value for b ");
result = a + b;

public static double GetValue(string input )
{
    double value;
    Console.WriteLine(input);

    while (!Double.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out value)) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("invalid value please try again..");
    }

    return value;
}
```

The reason I think this is slightly better, is because you isolate the logic of parsing into the function, so you need only one call to double.TryParse. Moreover, if someone would type an incorrect value for b, in your code they would need to start over with the value for a, where in my code, they just have to retry b.